# Como traer al frente un formulario de win forms en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando hacer que mi formulario este siempre en frente de las demas aplicaciones. Esto es debido a que generalmente queda abierto al fondo de todo y la aplicacion no iniciara por que es un formulario para actualizar.
Codigo del formulario que llama al que quiero dejar en frente:

`Update i = new Update();`

`i.ShowDialog();`

Codigo del formulario Update:

```
    private void Update_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BringToFront();
    }
```

Probe agregando BringToFront a un timer pero sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: El showdialog es para que quede abierto y no te permita hacer otra cosa hasta que lo cierres dentro de tu aplicacion, pero vos queres que este al frente de todas las aplicaciones abiertas en tu escritorio?

Comment: Coloqué una respuesta que creo te haya resultado útil, si lo consideras correcto, te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `TopMost` del formulario permite ubicar tu formulario en primer plano, por encima de las demás aplicaciones, siempre que otra aplicación no haga lo mismo, en un momento posterior al que lo hizo la tuya.
El código quedaría como sigue:

```
private void Update_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           this.TopMost = true;
    }
```

Puedes probar actualizar la propiedad periódicamente, para garantizar que siempre tu aplicación este en primer plano.